# Adding parameters to a dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

My sql procedure is

```
 SET @query='UPDATE '+@tbl+' SET  auth_Date='''+@authDate+'''
    ,authorized_By_ID=@AuthID
    ,authorized=1 WHERE '+@col+'=@Id;
    IF(@@ERROR=0) SET @reVal=1 ELSE SET @reVal=-1' 


    EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, N'@reVal int OUTPUT', 
    @reVal,N'@AuthID int',@AuthID,N'@Id int',@Id
```

Here @AuthID is Datetime, @AuthID and @Id is int

1) How can I pass arguments .
2) There is an error is coming
  `Conversion failed when converting 
   date and/or time from character string.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass argument definition in the second parameter, followed by the arguments, in the order declared:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query, 
    N'@AuthID int, @Id int, @reVal int OUTPUT', 
    @AuthID, @Id, @reVal OUTPUT;
```

Any reason why you don't pass @authDate also as a parameter? specially since datetime types are notoriously error prone when converted to strings, due to locale settings.

Last, you should [use TRY/CATCH blocks instead of @@ERROR checks](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/).